# Run all files in a directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I want to have a config directory, with every config in a file. So at the start of my react app, everything in the config folder runs. Also if you have a better approach I would be happy to know

For example (/config):

**firebase.js**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
 // ...
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

**material-ui.js**

```
import coolThings from 'whatever'
// ...
export theme
```

You get the idea

Comment: Does each script need to be executed in the same environment or in isolation (i.e. are you just basically trying to run `node firebase`, `node material-ui`, etc...?)?

Comment: they are in the same enviroment, I don't want to have a huge js document with over 800 lines with different configs. I want to have a document for each config and run each document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index file inside config, and import every config file there. Then import the config directory inside the main app. That way the imported directory will run the index.js (config/index.js), this will run every config file inside the config folder.